# A one word replacement when referring to multiple family members

Tags: single-word-requests

When you are saying something like

> I'm going Christmas shopping with my **aunt and uncle**.

is there a replacement for '*aunt and uncle*' that is one word?

If not, is the sentence grammatically correct?

Comment: "I'm going Christmas shopping with my relatives"

Comment: siblings, parents, cousins; no, no, nope. I think you found a hole. Now is it just in my knowledge?

Comment: Well, is it possible to be more specific than relatives or family? I don't think there's such word in the english language that's that specific, but saying "aunt and uncle" sounds... "wrong"

Comment: Don't worry, you've got it; there's absolutely nothing wrong with "aunt and uncle"- "*I'm going shopping with my aunt and uncle*" is exactly right.

Comment: Well that's good then. I still have that curiosity that's yet to be fed. But at least I know I'm not saying it wrong.

Comment: Is this specifically about the (nonexistent) hypernym of aunt and uncle or about the question in the title (which is 'relatives'?

Comment: I think my title is flawed, I didn't really know how to word it and keep it short. But yes, it is a hypernym of aunt and uncle. 

 
Essentially, an english equivalent version of tios (uncles and aunts combined or uncles).

Comment: It seems *tios* essential refers to 'uncles' and by cultural influence, may include a group that includes their spouses (the aunts) as well. At least technically. It may have come to mean 'aunts' later on. AFAIK, there's no such thing in English.

Comment: @Kris Not exactly. In the Romance languages, and certainly in Spanish, the male embraces the female.  So the parents of your cousin are your *tíos*, even though one is a *tío* and the other a *tía*. Similarly, one’s own parent are one’s *padres*, comprising a *padre* and *madre* both. It does not work this way so much in French, though.

Comment: @tchrist Nor in English, was my point.

Answer (score 1):

In the  context of OP's casual speech, one could say,

> I'm going Christmas shopping with my **folks**.

[TFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/folks):

> **4**. **folks** *Informal*
>   a. The members of one's family or childhood household; one's relatives.

Comment: The order of definitions in that link is interesting - I would have thought the parental definition would be primary. Perhaps drop the s and state "I'm going shopping with my **folk**"?

Comment: I agree with @lonstar. If I heard "folks" I would assume "parents". Kinfolk might work, but it sounds quite hillbilly to me.

Comment: **folks** can be interpreted as friends, especially in colloquial usage.

Comment: @ermanen Yes, but we don't use ***my** folks* when talking of buddies, *my* suggests a family relation.

Answer (score 0):

I think aunt and uncle sounds just fine.  If you want one word I would go with relatives.  Family (members) could be used too but some would take this as immediate family.